# Accessing this in jquery ajax success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  //Save new category information
  $('.save_cat').live('click', function() {

      cat_id =  $(this).attr("id").slice(4);
      cat_name = $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('.cat_name_edit').val();
      sort_order = $(this).parent().prev().children('.sort_order_edit').val();

      $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
               url: '../file/category/update_category',
               data: { 'cat_id' : cat_id, 
                       'sort_order' : sort_order,
                       'cat_name' : cat_name},
               beforeSend:function(){

                  //action while loading

               },
               success:function(data){

                   alert('hi');
                   $(this).html("Edit");

               },
               error:function(){

                   // failed request; give feedback to user
                   alert("An unexpected error has occurred. Your category could not be saved.");
               },  

               dataType : 'json'
      });
  });
```

In the success handler, I'm attempting to change the html of the clicked element from Save to Edit.  If I place this directly below the click handler for .save_cat, it works fine.  How can I do this once the request has been successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture its value in a variable local to the `live` handler.

```
$('.save_cat').live('click', function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    // These should be vars.
    var cat_id =  $that.attr("id").slice(4);
    ...
    $.ajax({ ...
        success: function() { $that.html("Edit"); }
```

FWIW, [`.delegate` is preferred](http://api.jquery.com/live/) over `.live` in jQuery < 1.7, and [`.on` is preferred](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery 1.7+][2](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: first line of the live handler should be `var element = $(this);` then manipulate the variable `element` on your `success` handler.