# I how can achieve the parent or nearest element with `this` object in `$.post` jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I how can achieve the parent element with `this` object in `$.post` jquery.
What i see, when i log that as `$(this)`, i get information on `POST` request details.
How can achieve that nearest or parent element with `this` or `any element` object.

I got know that, `this` is an object in `POST` request, so it get details for request.

### HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><span class="remove-file-confirm" id="aa" file-name="whatsup"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="remove-file-confirm" id="bb" file-name="gotstuck"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Script

```
$(".remove-file-confirm").click(function(){

    var rconfirm = confirm("Are you sure, want to delete this file");

    if (rconfirm) {
        var rfileid = $(this).attr("id");
        var rfilecode = $(this).attr("file-name");

        $.post("ajx_delete_file.php", {fid:rfileid, fcd:rfilecode}, function(return_datad){
            if (return_datad == "good") {
                var k = $(this);
                //$(this).closest("<tr>").hide();
                console.log(k); // show information on post request
                // how can i achieve .remove-file-confirm nearest tr element
            } else {
                alert("Cannot delete this file");
                console.log(return_datad);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#'+rfileid).closest("tr").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution for this question, but there good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327551/accessing-this-in-jquery-ajax-success-handler

Answer (score 2):

You could pre-assign the element when ur in the scope of the element like this.

Assign a variable before you run `post`:

```
var $parent = $(this).closest("tr")
```

Then use it inside post :

```
$parent.hide();
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
$(".remove-file-confirm").click(function(){

    var rconfirm = confirm("Are you sure, want to delete this file");
    var $parent = $(this).closest("<tr>")
    if (rconfirm) {
        var rfileid = $(this).attr("id");
        var rfilecode = $(this).attr("file-name");

        $.post("ajx_delete_file.php", {fid:rfileid, fcd:rfilecode}, function(return_datad){
            if (return_datad == "good") {
                $parent.hide();
                //$(this).closest("<tr>").hide();
                console.log(k); // show information on post request
                // how can i achieve .remove-file-confirm nearest tr element
            } else {
                alert("Cannot delete this file");
                console.log(return_datad);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it has to be    $(this).closest("tr");

Comment: @C.kosan oops did not see that. edited.